# Why my browser add "file:///" before my links?

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser, hyperlink

I have a little problem with my browser or my links. I'm in local with wamp.
I define CONSTANT in PHP like this :

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define("RACINE", $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'e-mmobilier' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

But when I go to my page, I see "file:///" before my links and it doesn't open them. 
In console I see my links are good

```
<a class="nav-a" href="C:/Users/fares/Code\e-mmobilier\index.php">Accueil</a>
```

Why it add "file:///" ????

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Because you are doubleclicking on the file using FileManager. Therefore it never goes via the web server and therefore all Server Variables dont exist. Also there is nothing to interpret your PHP code

Comment: Where is the DocumentRoot of your web server?

Comment: Which WAMP are you running? XAMPP or WAMPServer or ......

Comment: A var dump of DOCUMENT ROOT : 'C:/Users/fares/Code'. My version of WAMP is 3.2.0.

Comment: Read http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

Comment: And then http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean when you say "doublecliking on the file using FileManager". I just write my code, save and go to my browser to see the result.

Comment: what do you enter in the browser address bar? Do you key something like  `localhost/xxx.php`

Comment: Exactly, localhost/e-mmobilier/...

Comment: And if you add `http://` in front of the `localhost?

Comment: When I add `http://` it disappears and displays : `localhost/...`

Comment: Yea, thats quite normal

Comment: So what was all thsi about `file:///` then

Comment: Your `href="C:/Users/fares/Code\e-mmobilier\index.php` should be `href="e-mmobilier\index.php"` definitely not with the `C:/` and full path

Comment: Lol I don't know why when I want to click it add `file:///`. After reading the documentation, I think I am using wamp badly. I changed the "www" folder. I do not use virtual host for each project but rather each project is a sub-folder of localhost.

Comment: Always BEST to use a Virtual Host. That way your site eill move to a live site so much easier and without directory leven issues

Comment: True. Thanks for your help ;)